# How can I take checkbox dropdown value if it is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using bootstrap dropdown checkbox. I am able to take a checkbox value when I click on checkbox.

My problem is that if I have already checked the box by default, I cannot take that value using this script.

[Demo link](https://jsbin.com/heteven/edit?html,js,console,output)

```js
var options = [];

$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(event) {

  var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
    val = $target.attr('data-value'),
    $inp = $target.find('input'),
    idx;



  if ((idx = options.indexOf(val)) > -1) {
    options.splice(idx, 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $inp.prop('checked', false)
    }, 0);
  } else {
    options.push(val);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $inp.prop('checked', true)
    }, 0);
  }

  $(event.target).blur();

  console.log(options);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" checked/>&nbsp;Option 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 5</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 6</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this simpler script?

```js
const getOptions = () => $('.dropdown-menu input:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).closest("label").data("value");
}).get()

let options = getOptions();
console.log(options);

$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event) {
  options = getOptions();
  $(event.target).blur(); // possibly not necessary 
  console.log(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <label class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" checked/>&nbsp;Option 1</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 2</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 3</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 4</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 5</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" />&nbsp;Option 6</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My earlier script was works even I clicked on text. this script working only when i clicked on checkbox. @mplungjan

Comment: See update. I changed the anchor to a label as this is how to check a checkbox when clicking the text. You need to change the CSS accordingly